# What is the proper way to comment when receiving a value from user?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn proper code formatting in Java, the conventions, keeping it neat and putting proper comments.

I am baffled, however, on what wording I should use when I call for a JOptionPane input dialog in order to 'receive' a user-specified value.

What is normally used in this situation?

I am using "// Get user input", but I just read an article explaining that 'getting' something has an entirely different meaning whatsoever.

Comment: I think `//get user input` is actually fine. I also use to write `//read user input`, but i think both are ok.

Comment: "Get user input" seems fine.  "Get" is also often seen in "getter"-type methods used to access private variables, but I don't think it would cause confusion.  There's also "prompt user for input", "fetch user input", etc., but I'd just leave "get" and move on with your business.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'll just stick with Get for now. Cheers everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't stress too much about the exact language of the comments. You just want them to be clear so that whom ever comes behind you to maintain the code will understand what is going on. Don't worry about syntax for comments, it really isn't that important.

You could say:

```
//get user input
//read user input
//take user input
```

Honestly, it is one of the least important things to worry about. Just make sure that people know what you are doing. I'd focus on making the code itself clean and well-formatted, not the comments. It's important to have comments, as most programmers don't take the time to do it, but it isn't the most important thing.

It is more important to watch your verbiage when naming methods/classes/functions/variables. Not the comments.

:)

Comment: Thanks! I'll make sure to learn more about keeping my code clean and well formatted. Cheers!

Comment: No problem man! Comments are important, and more programmers should use them, but again, don't get hung up the specific words used in them. That should be reserved for the methods/classes/variables. Your heart is in the right place, just place the effort on the  right areas :)

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion comments should explain **why** you do something (if it is not obvious). The code itself should tell **how** it is done.

- If you cannot understand what the code does, the code might be bad.
- If you understand the code but don't understand why a specific action is executed, you are missing a comment.

So instead of adding a comment like `// read user input` you should name your methods and variables in a useful way:

```
...
String userInput = getUserInput(); 
...
```

No comment needed to understand this.